# Check for duplicates in object-array and count them

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I need to check for all duplicates in an array with objects like this:

```
var array = [{ 
    id: '123', 
    value: 'Banana', 
    type: 'article'
},
{ 
    id: '124', 
    value: 'Apple', 
    type: 'article'
},
{ 
    id: '125', 
    value: 'Banana', 
    type: 'images'
}]
```

Now I need the result like:

```
{ 'Banana': 2 }
```

That means I just need to know about duplicates for `value`, and I want to know how many times there is the same value

I thought about something like

```
var counts = {};
array.forEach(function(x) { counts[x.value] = (counts[x.value] || 0) + 1; });
```

But this gives me just the counting values for all objects... I need the counting for the duplicates (not all).

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `'value'` parameter from each element and save in another array and simply check the occurrence of the `'value'` using `.indexOf()`

```
    var arr = [{ 
    id: '123', 
    value: 'Banana', 
    type: 'article'
},
{ 
    id: '124', 
    value: 'Apple', 
    type: 'article'
},
{ 
    id: '125', 
    value: 'Banana', 
    type: 'images'
},
{ 
    id: '126', 
    value: 'Apple', 
    type: 'images'
},
{ 
    id: '126', 
    value: 'Kiwi', 
    type: 'images'
}];

var itemCollection = [];
var duplicates = [];
$.each(arr,function(i,o)
{  
  if(itemCollection.indexOf(arr[i]["value"]) == -1)
     itemCollection.push(arr[i]["value"]);
  else
     duplicates.push("Duplicate found :" + arr[i]["value"]);
});

alert(duplicates);
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6he7n9d1/1/

Comment: But this doesn't give me the amount of duplicated values. If there are three 'bananas' -> 3

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). If ES5 built-ins are not guaranteed, you can use shims, a utility library, or just simple for-loops.

```js
var array = [{
  id: '123',
  value: 'Banana',
  type: 'article'
}, {
  id: '124',
  value: 'Apple',
  type: 'article'
}, {
  id: '125',
  value: 'Banana',
  type: 'images'
}]

var counts = array.reduce(function(counts, item) {
  var value = item.value
  counts[value] = counts[value] + 1 || 1
  return counts
}, {})

var duplicateCounts = Object.keys(counts).filter(function(value) {
  return counts[value] > 1
}).reduce(function(duplicateCounts, value) {
  duplicateCounts[value] = counts[value]
  return duplicateCounts
}, {})

console.log(duplicateCounts)
```